# Swift - how can i fix this two error?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cordova

Can anyone please advise, how to fix this 2 error?

Using:
    `Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b)
    Apple Swift version 2.1 (700.1.101.6 700.1.76).`

Installed:

```
npm install -g cordova ios-deploy
cordova create <name>
cordova platform add ios android
cordova platform add browser --usegit
cordova plugin add http:...git

Go platforms/ios and click on [ProjectName].xcodeproj to open it with XCode
Go to your project settings
In General, change Deployment Target to 7.0 or above
Go to Build Settings and change:
a. Valid Architectures => armv7
b. Build Active Architecture Only => No
c. Runpath Search Paths => $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new too but did you try Clean(Product->Clean) and then Build(Product->Build)? I have resolved a lot of similar issues with clean build. May be it helps.

Comment: YES - i did clean it and still same. Can we join Chat we need to fix it together, others are not welcoming  us as you can see voting me minus when-ever i am asking anything related to swift.

Comment: Did you had time to look at it please? so that we can fix it